# Taking data from multiple xls files and saving as csv with >65000 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I regularly run a macro in Excel 2010 to loop through a number of .xls files, copying the data from each into a .xlsm file and then saving as a .csv.  When I save the csv, however, the document when I next open it has been truncated to c.65,000 rows.  I know that this is about the limit of an xls document, but I don't understand why it would happen when I save an xlsm as a csv.

I'm splitting the files into batches as a workaround, but my inability to fix this annoys me every time.  Any ideas?  (Or if I've totally misdiagnosed the issue, that would be useful to know as well so I can think about what else might be happening).

This is the extract of the code I'm using to save the document:

```
Sub save_tracker_csv()
    
    Dim today_date As String
    today_date = Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Sheets(1).Activate
    
    Dim batch As Integer
    batch = Application.InputBox("Enter a batch number")

--save copy for archiving
        Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = _
        "N:\Operations\Practice exports\CSV\" & today_date & "_" & batch & ".csv"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
        
 --copy for database
        strFilename = _
        "N:\Operations\Practice exports\CSV\import_tbl_" & batch & ".csv"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
        
        
        MsgBox "Your file has been saved"
        
        Set wb = Nothing
 End sub
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: how are you viewing the csv?  is it in an older version of excel?  If you open the csv in a text editor instead, are the rows missing?

Comment: This cannot be the full code, you are not looping anything.  And if you are opening .xls to save them to individual .csv then yes the limit is 65k rows.  It does not appear your code is doing what your verbiage is detailing, so it is hard to help.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner.  It's in Excel 2010 as well, but that's a good point to consider.  I've been focussing on the code but it's probably something silly to do with how I'm viewing it.  I'll try running the complete version and see if your suggestion works.  Thank you!  (Just seen your second reply - no it's not the full code.  It's a relatively lengthy macro that I didn't want to waste everyone's time with.  Your prompt is enough to give me something to try - I can post more if I continue to be stuck :))